Excel Conditional Formatting Formula Not Working on Cells
I am annoyed that I am struggling to figure this out and I expect it is very easy, so thank you in advance.
I need to figure out the formula to conditional format a cell based upon the value in the cell I want the format to be applied to AND the value in a cell in the same column but above the range I am applying it to.
I know its a dumb solution but I am apparently not using the correct search  terms to figure out where my mistake is.
Thank you in advance.
I have built a formula that gives me the correct trues and falses, but for some reason I am struggling to get it to work in conditional formatting.
=AND(B16="e",GetFillColor(B$5)=20)
results in TRUE as a formula in a cell, and if I fill right and down
to apply it to the full range, the formula works for all cells. But for some reason, when I put it into
the "Use formula to determine which cells to format" conditional formatting option, and set the range to $B8:$AD$31, there is no format change for the cells that have "e".
What I want:
B16 has "e" and B5=20. I want to change the color of B16.
B17 has "f" and B5=20. I do not want to change the color of B17.
AD15 has "e" and AD5=40. I do not want to change the color of AD15.
AD30 has "f" and AD5=40. I do not want to change the color of AD30.
EDIT:
I tried applying responses from last night and they did not work. BUT,  when I wrote this last night, my UDF GetFillColor() was working, and now it is not. I built that function from guidance from another stackoverflow comment that linked back to http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010780_Colors_in_an_IF_Function.html.
Here is the UDF that I have:
Function GetFillColor(Rng As Range) As Long
    GetFillColor = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to stack exchange. You need to specify your problem a little more clearly. Do you really want GetFillColor(B$5)=20 to determine colours of other cells or 'B$5', $B$5 or B5=20. If I have understood what you want then select the range you want to conditionally color first and then go to create rule from formula and input =AND(B16="e",$B$5=20). If that works OK then add another rule to set AD15 back to normal if AD5=40

@Martin Brown - I want GetFillColor() to check the color in row 5 of the same column I am, and if the colorindex=20, and the content of  the cell I am in ="e", return TRUE.

I got it working. Sometimes I was also making the mistake nkhalvi solved for, but it seems that my issue was with my UDF.  Does anyone know why it would be working just fine and then all of a sudden kick and error and stop working at all? I have to go back to an old version and recreate the macro and maybe it will work and maybe it wont.

Conditional formula needs to be entered with the first cell in the "Applies to:" range selected, so here's how to apply it with B8 selected:

A dummy UDF GetFillColor is used for demonstration, it simply returns the argument
With B$5, reference row is fixed with $5, while the column is relative
B8 entered with relative reference for both row and column


